# у меня есть ошибки в коде, как их исправить?

Tags: c#, unity3d

```
Assets\Scripts\AllShapesJump.cs(8,34): error CS0027: Keyword 'this' is not available in the current context
Assets\Scripts\AllShapesJump.cs(8,108): error CS0119: 'Rigidbody2D' is a type, which is not valid in the given context
```

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class AllShapesJump : MonoBehaviour
{
    private int i = 0;
    private Rigidbody2D rbthis = gameObject.transform.GetChild(0).GetChild(0).gameObject.GetComponent(Rigidbody2D);

    public void ShapesJump() 
    {
        for (; i < transform.childCount; i++) 
        {
            if (Mathf.Abs(rbthis.velocity.y) < 0.05f)
            {
                rbthis.AddForce(new Vector2(Random.Range(-25f, 25f), 35f), ForceMode2D.Impulse);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Строку

```
private Rigidbody2D rbthis = gameObject.transform.GetChild(0).GetChild(0).gameObject.GetComponent(Rigidbody2D);
```

сделать

```
private Rigidbody2D rbthis = null;
```

А вот в методе `Awake` или `Start` уже сделать инициализацию

```
rbthis = gameObject.transform.GetChild(0).GetChild(0).gameObject.GetComponent(Rigidbody2D);
```

---

для решения проблемы с

> 'Rigidbody2D' is a type, which is not valid in the given context

Надо испльзовать взятие компонента либо так

```
GetComponent(typeof(Rigidbody2D)) as Rigidbody2D
```

либо

```
GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
```

либо

```
GetComponent("Rigidbody2D") as Rigidbody2D;
```

Это написано в [документации](https://docs.unity3d.com/ru/2019.4/ScriptReference/GameObject.GetComponent.html)

Comment: точно не дубликат? https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1440449/373567

Comment: не знаю. я не искал дубли. просто ответил сразу))

Comment: осталась ошибка Assets\Scripts\AllShapesJump.cs(12,87): error CS0119: 'Rigidbody2D' is a type, which is not valid in the given context
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class AllShapesJump : MonoBehaviour
{
    private int i = 0;
    private Rigidbody2D rbthis = null;

    void Start() 
    {
        rbthis = gameObject.transform.GetChild(0).GetChild(0).gameObject.GetComponent(Rigidbody2D);
    }
дальше ограничение

Comment: @nikihouse потому что надо либо `GetComponent(typeof(Rigidbody2D)) as Rigidbody2D` либо `GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();`  либо  `GetComponent("Rigidbody2D") as Rigidbody2D;` --- доки https://docs.unity3d.com/ru/2019.4/ScriptReference/GameObject.GetComponent.html

Comment: `GetComponent(Rigidbody2D)` стоит отметить это в ответе

Comment: @aepot ок. добавил